# Getting core dump freeing memory allocated by getline()

Tags: c

I am getting the core dump and I have been looking and it seems I am doing everything right.

```
int len = 0;
char *buff = NULL;
size_t sz;
if(getline(&buff,&sz, stdin) > 0){
    while(isalpha(*buff++))
        ++len;
       printf(" 1st word %d characters long ",len);
}
free(buff);
```

Comment: `buff` no longer points to the beginning of the block of memory allocated by `getline()`. You can no longer pass it to `free()`. Save a copy of the original address or use a separate pointer to iterate.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Turn that into an answer

Comment: Will do. Give me a sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

You fail in (1) so you can't do (2). Specifically, what is happening is `getline()` allocates storage and assigns the beginning address for the allocated block to `buff`. You then use `buff` to iterate over the string calling `*buff++`. When you are done iterating, `buff` no longer points to (holds the beginning address of) the block of memory allocated by `getline()`.

When you attempt to pass `buff` to `free()`, an error occurs because you are attempting to free an address that was not previously allocated by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

Use a separate pointer to iterate with, e.g. `char *p = buff;` within your read loop and iterate with `p`. (you can also use an index for iterating, e.g. `buf[i]` without changing the original address `buff` holds) Then you can pass `buff` to `free()`.